# Need a solution to capturing scroll event on Facebook iFramed app page

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, cross-domain, facebook-iframe

I have developed an application page in Facebook which, of course lives in an `iFrame`. I want to be able to affect an element in the `iFrame` content upon page scroll (the main page/canvas page). Using jQuery the code within the content page would be:

```
parent.$(window).scroll(function(){
    do something
});
```

In a normal situation where the `iFrame` and parent window are in the same domain this would work, but due to the security restrictions between different domains, this is not allowed. I've search the web extensively and have not found any solutions for this. Is there any cross domain fix, or any way of coding this to simply allow for a capture of the scrolling event of the main page?

Answer (score 0):

I have fought with this exact issue extensively. For my situation I wanted to remove the scroll bar and also scroll to the top of the page when a user switched between pages. I used this code just before the /head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 1000});
  FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
}
</script>
```

The issue, as you have learned, is the cross site attacks. So, Firefox for example disallows ANY such property. It all depends on exactly what you want to do. If you reply with some more information about exactly what action you are trying to perform perhaps I can offer more advice. The real bottom line is that you will have to create some sort of hack to accomplish your task and it is entirely possible that your task simply cannot happen. I was very bummed to learn of this change. I think that Chrome has also deprecated this feature and will soon stop it all together.

Brandon